# Scanning a Text File Line by Line in PHP

Tags: php, string, file

So I have been working recently on a questionnaire script in php and I wrote a tool that would output a single txt file with a list of questions, each on it's own line. The file would look like so..

**1 "Shopping for items is very important to me.." 2 3 4 5s 6**   *//notice the 5s*

**2 "I love it when it is a rainy day" 4 8s 12 16 32s**

The first number is the Questions id number. Next within the double quotes is the question itself.

The next numbers that follow are id's of other questions that relate to that questions.

In the case of "5s", that is a special question and I want the file reader to detect if the number has an s after it.

```
$file = fopen("output.txt", "r");
$data = array();

while (!feof($file)) 
{
   $data[] = fgets(trim($file));
}

fclose($file);

// Now I have an Array of strings line by line
// Whats next now??
```

My question is how can I code something that will read the file in this order:

(1)..The Question's ID number..

("Shopping for items is very important to me..")...Then the actual question itself disregarding the double quotes

(2 3 4 5s 6)...Then the actual numbers while being aware that some may be 'special'.

Can Someone PLease Help Me!!! THANKS!!

Comment: With which part do you need help? What's the roadblock that you hit?

Comment: I also don't see any parentheses in the sample data.  Did you mean "double quotes?"

Comment: I modified my question futher. Thanks to all! Also parentheses was a typo, I meant double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of processing the file in the format you provided:

```
$file = fopen("output.txt", "r");
$data = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $line = trim(fgets($file, 2048));
   if (preg_match('/^(\d+)\s+"([^"]+)"\s*([\ds\s]+)?$/', $line, $matches)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'num' => $matches[1],
            'question' => $matches[2],
            'related' => $matches[3],
        );
   }
}
fclose($file);

print_r($data);
```

And the result you will get from print_r($data) is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [num] => 1
            [question] => Shopping for items is very important to me..
            [related] => 2 3 4 5s 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [num] => 2
            [question] => I love it when it is a rainy day
            [related] => 4 8s 12 16 32s
        )

)
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the related questions, so it is currently a string, but you could process this further into an array if you needed to.